# What should we expect from Simbody?

Tags: physics

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I can notice on Bitbucket that you are working to integrate Simbody into Gazebo.
This sound like a good news, since so far ODE is very disappointing for legged robots.

What should be expect from Simbody in terms of accuracy and performance, compared with ODE and the upcoming Bullet?

When will we have a first release including Simbody?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1728/what-should-we-expect-from-simbody?/) by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/253/davide-faconti/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) on 2013-03-11**:
Same question goes for RTQL8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The major difference/advantage between ODE/Bullet and SimBody/RTQL8 is that ODE/Bullet uses maximal coordinates and SimBody/RTQL8 use minimal coordinates.

The first release with SimBody will be late 2013 or early 2014.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2013-12-16**:
Is this schedule still accurate? I'm working on a project that is using both simbody and gazebo and may be able to chip in some effort if it's helpful.